# Cut text with condition and append other column text to it

Tags: javascript, excel

I have a large table of almost 5000 rows in Excel. My problem is like this.

I have these column data:

```
column A       column B      column C
a-b-c-5.html   d             e
```

now I want a new column lets say D having data like:

```
column A       column B      column C      column D 
a-b-c-5.html   d             e             a-b-c-d-e.html
```

How can I do it for all rows simultaneously (may be using excel formula or using javascript)?

Comment: So basically, you're trying to remove `5` and put `d` and `e` before `.html`?

Comment: please describe if your data is either fixed size or if the hyphens seperating individual tokens are at least reliable .... and post some example code ... what have you tried so far?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.Ya exactly I want to remove the last text before .html.One more thing data size is not fixed however it is hyphen seperated like illuminated-wall-art-20965.html,illuminated-wall-art-20966.html

Comment: Do you perhaps have more examples of how the data might appear?

Comment: like old data is illuminated-wall-cat-20965.html,illuminated-wall-art-20966.html  and now I want to make these data like illuminated-wall-cat-text1-text2.html,illuminated-wall-art-text1-text2.html   .Extremely sorry for wrong formatting

Comment: An excel formula that concatenates the values after applying `SUBSTITUTE()` to the value in the first column might do it, Though i'm not sure if `SUBSTITUTE()` works with regex (for the numeric part).

Comment: I normally copy the data to notepad++, replace to my heart's content with regex and paste it back into excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try in column D

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("#",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","#",3)))&B1&"-"&C1&".html"
```

Copy down.

looks like:
[image]

If your URLs have a varying number of dashes, then you can use

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("#",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","#",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","")))))&B1&"-"&C1&".html"
```

[image]

Comment: Also I used =CONCATENATE("text1","-",B2,"-",C2)  and it worked well on a new column.BTW thanx to show me the way to do

Comment: Yeah, concatenate() works, but it is the most overrated function ever. =A1&B1 is exactly the same as =Concatenate(A1,B1) --  Use a & sign instead of the comma and drop the word "concatenate" and the brackets. Same difference. Less typing.